# flexview illegal mix of collations error

Tags: mysql, materialized-views

I try to setup flexview to have support of materialize view in foor MySQL, but this error occurred :

```
PHP Strict standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Console/Getopt.php on line 109
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/arash/application/flexviews/consumer/setup_flexcdc.php:0
PHP   2. get_commandline() /home/arash/application/flexviews/consumer/setup_flexcdc.php:29
PHP   3. Console_Getopt->getopt2() /home/arash/application/flexviews/consumer/setup_flexcdc.php:14
PHP   4. Console_Getopt->doGetopt() /usr/share/php/Console/Getopt.php:75
PHP Strict standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically in /home/arash/application/flexviews/consumer/setup_flexcdc.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/arash/application/flexviews/consumer/setup_flexcdc.php:0
PHP   2. get_commandline() /home/arash/application/flexviews/consumer/setup_flexcdc.php:29
setup starting
SQL_ERROR IN STATEMENT:
DELETE bcs.* FROM `binlog_consumer_status` bcs where exec_master_log_pos >= master_log_size and server_id=1 AND master_log_file not in (select log_name from log_list)
DELETE bcs.* FROM `binlog_consumer_status` bcs where exec_master_log_pos >= master_log_size and server_id=1 AND master_log_file not in (select log_name from log_list)
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

why does this error occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your database is using UTF8 as the client or server character set, but the temporary table created by flexcdc is using latin1.

You could try to change the character set in the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE that creates log_list.

Comment: how can I change the character set in the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE? where?

Comment: The lastest version of Flexviews in github has a complete fix for this issue.